# TFS express 2013 login failed from outside my network

Tags: iis, tfs

**TFSPreview cloud service is not an option for us**

I have install TFS express 2013 on my company network, we have developers at many place in the world so we want give access to the TFS server, but they never can successfully authenticate in the TFS Website, we can perfectly use it from inside.

In the IIS the tfs application: the authentication is set to Windows Authentication others are disable.

We have check the IIS logs and there is not firewall problem, their reach the server but always return a http 401 response.

My server is Windows 2012 and IIS 8.0, and i can't see where activate the Digest authentication as #Mike suggest

Any idea?

thanks in advance

Comment: Are your users connectin via vpn? Also, how many users as tfs express has limits.

Comment: our user are connecting via http, we are talking about 4 user but they are around the world. Tip: my user are behind a http proxy, they can't  open a vpn

Comment: Can any of them connect? 401 means unauthorized so they might not be putting in the correct credentials. Have you verified that they are entering the correct domain name and that the they are a valid collection user?

Comment: yes i do even i have make the test by my self with the same result. [machinename]\[username] and request username and password over an over again

Comment: Are these users accounts on the local machine? You need to amke sure the accoutns arein the valid collection users tfs group. Can you verify this?

Comment: I jsut did a little more digging (all my tfs users are domain users). According to Microsoft you ahve to configure tfs for basic or digest authentication for external users: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833874(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i have not configure yet Basic Authentication and Digest Authentication, let me try it and will let you know, thanks good tip

Comment: My server is Windows 2012 and IIS 8.0, and i can't see where activate the Digest authentication as #Mike suggest

Comment: I'm not a security expert but basic should be fine if it is done over ssl (again I am no expert).

Comment: If you've got 4 users and TFS Express, switch to Visual Studio Online (through visualstudio.com). Still free, more features, and you won't have to deal with this issue at all.